# How to use SPM8 to display features?

Tags: matlab, batch-processing

As we know, SPM (Statistical Parametric Mapping) uses GLM and t-test to analyze data and display data. If I uses other methods e.g. searchlight to analyze the data,then how to draw the selected voxels? I got samples images about the selected voxels by using t-test and searchlight. I know how to use GLM and t-test to analyze data by using SPM and then display the selected voxels. But I do not know if I use other methods to do feature selection by using Matlab Code, then after that how to display the selected voxels?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @UnknownOctopus, when using SPM and t-test to process the data, it can be saved as batch file.

Comment: A Windows batch file exclusively containing commands found [here](http://ss64.com/nt/)? Because that's what the [batch-file] tag is for.